# Linear regression, y=mx+b. Input x to get the y value using vectors

Tags: r

I'm new to R and a pretty novice programmer. I've come up with the following, but I'm stumped on this question. I don't need the answer, just a nudge in the right direction.

````
x <- c(1,5,7,9,10,22)
y <- c(22.2,33.4,45.7,50.2,55.9,89.1)

#a = B0 b = B1

linear_regression <- function(x,y){
  x2 <- x * x 
  y2 <- y * y
  xy <- x * y
  a = (sum(y)*sum(x2) - sum(x)*sum(xy))/(length(x)*sum(x2) - (sum(x)^2))
  b = (length(x)*sum(xy) - sum(x)*sum(y))/(length(x)*sum(x2) - (sum(x)^2))
  coeff = c(a,b)
  return(coeff)
}
linear_regression(x,y)

#2 Using the betas you generated, make a new prediction for the value of y, given the value of x is 40```
````

Comment: Check your formulas against the formulas and the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Numerical_example

Comment: Use the “lm()” function to check your results.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the predicted Y will equal B0 + B1 * X (where B0 and B1 are the estimated coefficients) and you should be on your way